Family move into or inspects house where weird things happen
All I can remember is that it's a horror movie where a family moves into a newly built house, and there's only maybe like two or three other houses built but for the most part it's just them. I think the kids consist of a younger brother and an older teenage sister? I don't really remember much else.
EDIT: Just remembered a few more details. Okay so I think they weren't moved into the house yet and they went to go visit it a couple times (like popping in to look around or just kind of being in there), and like weird things start happening here and there (as any typical horror movie).
Now I'm not sure 100% if they themselves were moving into the house, or if the father was selling the houses in the neighborhood or not. 
Also it's a fairly new movie, no older than 2012.
Can someone figure this movie out for me?

This is the premise of half of the horror movies out there :P

Sounds like the The Amityville Haunting (2011) to me
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Haunting
Or maybe some of the other Amityville films: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Horror#Films
